# BlackBerry Database Slow Performance

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, blackberry

I'm making use of a 5 mb SQLite db in my app, on app's 1st use the db is being copied to the device memory card.

The problem is that the db querying is very slow.

Any suggestions to performance improvments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take a look at these tips in order to optimize your SQLite database performance:
[Best practice: Optimizing SQLite database performance](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8682/BP_Optimizing_SQLite_database_performance_767361_11.jsp)